# How does non-useful work manifest in this irreversible example?

Tags: thermodynamics, work, reversibility

a common example for irreversible process given is the rapid expansion of  a piston due to sudden reduction in external pressure(as against very slow reduction in a reversible case). In this case, it is stated that maximum useful work derived is less, because piston does less useful work (as illustrated via area under the curve in P-V work).But this is mathematical explanation more or less. What I am trying to understand is intuitively, why does this happen? why is work done less? where does the "non-useful " work end up as? assume it is a frictionless system. Describe at a microscopic level, keeping it less mathematical.

My guess: the molecules of gas within piston chamber end up doing compression-expansion work of some sort on themselves which doesn't show up as useful work. But I am not able to visualize this.
also in this example has the entropy of system increased as well as surroundings? or only system? or both?

Comment: Where is it stated that useful work is less? Can you post an image of the text, or provide a link?

Comment: Part of the potential to do work is lost as a result of  *viscous dissipation* associated with the rapid deformation of the gas within the cylinder.  The lost work is converted to internal energy of the gas (i.e., higher temperature).  Think of a spring and damper in parallel.  In a rapid deformation, some of the energy stored in the spring is lost by viscous damping, but in a slow deformation,  most of the energy stored in the spring converts to useful work.  A gas behaves in an analogous way.

Comment: Sammy, it is irreversible process, so you don't derive maximum possible useful work out of it, that's what I meant

Comment: Thanks Chester, yes "viscous dissipation" is sort of what I was looking for to visualize, that helps a lot. So the rise in internal energy of the gas can lead to entropy increase of the system? In this case piston does work on surroundings as it pushes out on the system. Without doing any calculations can we say entropy of both system(gas within chamber) and surroundings(because of work done on it)increases ? consider both isolated as well as a closed system(which permits heat transfer)

Comment: in a closed but not isolated system  this increase in internal energy of the system can lead to heat transfer out to the surroundings, so why is it still considered "non-useful"? Is only P-V work considered useful?

Comment: Chester, after reading Philip's reply, expansion can cause drop in temperature right? so Temp. rise due to rise in internal energy is cancelled out by this expansion effect? which dominates?

Comment: The temperature doesn't have to increase when viscous dissipation occurs.  It can also decrease less than if viscous dissipation were not occurring.  The entropy of an ideal gas increases with increasing temperature and increasing volume.  For irreversible expansion in contact with a constant temperature reservoir, the amount of work done on the surroundings is less than for reversible expansion, and the heat taken in by the system is less.  The change in entropy is greater than the irreversible heat transferred divided by the reservoir temperature.

Answer (score -1):

If the piston moves outwards faster than any of the molecules in the cylinder are moving, clearly no work will be done on the piston by the gas, nor, in the case of an ideal gas, will there be any any energy change. If the piston is moving out fast, but not as fast as before, clearly there will be some work done by the gas on the piston, but less than if it were moving out at a speed many times less than the rms speed of the molecules (quasi-statically).

It's not, then, a case of non-useful work taking the place of useful work – simply of not as much (useful) work being done as in the quasi-static case.

As for entropy, consider the case of an ideal gas expanding adiabatically. The entropy of the gas (assuming constant $C_V$) is $$S= C_V \ ln T + nR\ ln V+S_0.$$ It's easy to show that if the expansion is quasi-static, so that the gas does the maximum possible amount of work, the fall in entropy due to the fall in temperature exactly compensates for the rise in entropy due to the rise in volume. But if the expansion is too quick (see first paragraph) not as much work is done, so the fall in entropy due to the temperature fall does not compensate for the rise due to rise in volume; that is the entropy goes up. This is only one of many ways of understanding what's going on.

Comment: Philip, you talk about "fall in temperature" whereas Chester talks about rise in temperature due to viscous dissipation, so a bit confused. which effect dominates more? also, what about entropy of surroundings in this irreversible process? do they go up? you can assume 2 scenarios-closed(no mass transfer but energy transfer is there) and isolated(no type of transfer takes place)

Comment: I considered an ideal gas, to make life simple. When a  gas expands quasi-statically, pushing a piston, it does work, so, according to the First Law of Thermod, its internal energy falls, if the conditions are adiabatic (no heat exchange with surroundings). For an ideal gas, for which $\Delta U=nC_v \Delta T$, the temperature must fall. If the expansion is very rapid, less work will be done and the temperature will fall less! Entropy of surroundings won't change in this adiabatic process.

Comment: To leave no room for doubt as to what I'm saying: if a gas expands, without any heat flow into or out of it, its temperature falls. It falls most if it expands slowly, pushing a piston. If the expansion is very rapid, less work will be done by the gas, and its temperature will fall less. In the limit of the piston moving out at a speed many times greater than the rms speed of the molecules (or the gas expanding into a vacuum), there will be no fall in temperature for an ideal gas.

Comment: If the gas is not ideal, there will still be a fall in temperature in this extreme case for this reason... Although there is no change in the gas's total internal energy, it gains potential energy due to the molecules moving further apart (on average) against attractive forces, and therefore it loses (random) kinetic energy.

Comment: Thanks Philip,  I guess I should imagine a real gas as molecules with more potential interactions as compared to an ideal gas. Mathematically, how is this difference in internal energy drop treated between the 2 types of gases?(I have avoided math so far , but just for the sake of closure) also, what about viscous dissipation leading to increase in temp. as Chester pointed out? under what circumstance does that happen? you have talked about only cooling vs less cooling so far for the 2 gases. But can there be heating due to viscous dissipation in real gases?

Comment: " If the expansion is very rapid, less work will be done and the temperature will fall less! Entropy of surroundings won't change in this adiabatic process." but entropy of system has to increase right? because entropy of system+surroundings has to increase in irreversible process. so how does this entropy increase manifest itself in the system? Chester said it manifested itself as viscous dissipation. any other manifestations possible? do you agree?

Comment: Can we take the extreme case of the piston moving out much faster than the rms speed of the molecules? In that case no work is done by the expanding gas, and the change will also be very nearly adiabatic. So the First Law shows that there will be no change in internal energy. This applies to a real gas or an ideal gas. I'd better check that you're ok with this before saying any more.

Comment: Hi Philip, I am OK with that. So the next questions are: 1. how does this unchanged internal energy still affect the temperature of real and ideal gases?(you answered this earlier) 2. this is irreversible process .And lets say system is isolated. so entropy of system has to increase. so at a molecular level how does this entropy increase manifest itself as in real vs ideal gases?

Comment: In addition to the above, why I have trouble visualizing this is because I am unable to reconcile an increase in entropy  with the loss in temperature. Usually , intuitively, you associate increase in entropy with increase in temperature. But here, the temperature drops, at least for the real gas. Thanks for your patience on this

Comment: also, some work had to be done by the surroundings to make piston move rapidly outward right? say the piston had some weights. the "surroundings" had to remove those weights rapidly in order to facilitate rapid expansion of the piston. i.e the surroundings played  a part in creating a huge driving force. where does this get accounted for?

Comment: re your comment beginning "Hi Philip". Part 2. No easy answer (that I can give!) for the difference in entropy change for a real and ideal gas. But I doubt if this is terribly important. What you seem to have missed is that the _volume_  increase in itself gives rise to an entropy increase, even if the temperature remains constant: see the equation I quoted in my answer above. This also deals with your next comment, beginning "In addition". As for your last comment ("also…"):  just make the piston very light: negligible work needed to accelerate it.

Comment: or dispense with the piston altogether, and simply let the gas expand into a vacuum!

Comment: Before I comment on the viscous dissipation issue (if you're still concerned about it) I'd like to be sure that you're happy with my answers to your last three queries.

Comment: Thanks Philip,  very useful insights. I guess discussion around this question is going to be a lot useful to other members as well thanks to especialay you and Chester.

Comment: Yes, I missed the part about the increase in volume contributing to entropy(and this is because useful work is lost in gaining randomness ,i.e more statistical arrangement of molecules are possible for a given temperature contributing to higher entropy). And this increase in entropy might more than offset the fall in U and temperature. So please go ahead with your responses on the other part.

Comment: Have to admit, I don't see the logic of Chester's post. When the piston is pulled out fast, various processes will go on in the gas, some of which might be called 'viscous dissipation'. But if these are supposed to _raise_ the mean KE of the gas molecules, and hence the gas temperature, ask yourself where this energy is supposed to have come from. I'd be interested in your response.

Comment: When you've responded, I'll explain in a bit more detail how I think viscous dissipation fits into the picture.

Comment: Philip, for questions like these, I have to always think of 2 answers-one for ideal, one for real. Makes my life a bit difficult. I'll try. I visualized the gas molecules inside piston as some sort of spring. when you release pressure on spring it takes a while for it to equilibrate(back and forth movement). this might be explained away as viscous dissipation, molecules rubbing away on each other. Does it arise from some loss of built up potential energy, if at all? and are these kind of interactions valid for real gas only and not ideal gas?

Comment: but this viscous dissipation effect is also negated by expansion effect ultimately, resulting in temperature drop overall. Maybe the temperature increase is fleeting. Ultimately when the dust settles down, you have a net entropy increase and temp increase. I am just hypothesizing here

Comment: I love your "when the dust settles": it captures what I've hardly mentioned: that if the piston moves out very rapidly the gas goes through various non-equilibrium states before regaining (a different) equilibrium state. But I hope you're totally clear that if the expansion is adiabatic the temperature of this final state will be lower than that of the first (a) for an ideal gas if any at all work is done by the gas on the piston and (b) for a real gas (because of the PE increase) even if no work is done on the piston. So I hope you meant "temp _de_crease" near the end of your last post.

Comment: Now let's tackle this viscous dissipation thing. It occurs during the non-equilibrium stages (while the dust settles!). As the piston moves out rapidly, there will be a 'wind' of molecules in the cylinder, moving mainly towards the piston. While this is happening the gas will no longer be isotropic, and not all the molecules' KE will be in random form. When the 'wind' hits the piston, and possibly before, there'll be some 'layers' of molecules (speaking macroscopically) sliding over each other, with collisions occurring, and the energy will be quickly 're-randomised' – viscous dissipation.

Comment: The key thing is that the random energy generated in the dissipation has come (via a fleeting period when some of the energy is more organised) from the original random energy of the gas molecules. This is essentially energy conservation or First Law of Thermod: if no heat comes in  and no work is done ON the gas, the gas can't gain internal energy! [For a real gas there is a slight overall decrease in random KE, due to the molecules gaining PE as they get (on average) further apart. This will happen even if the piston is moving out so fast that no work is done on it.]

Comment: Philip, got it. The fact that a real gas can cool even if it has not done any work while expanding is probably what is exploited in expansion cooling/refrigeration etc. Is this related to Joule-Thomson cooling or is that a different mechanism? interestingly joule-Thomson effect has an inversion temperature beyond which any expansion causes warming rather than cooling. This inversion temp. seems to be a function of pressure as well temperature at the inlet. But thanks for your explanations. I consider my original question answered.

Comment: Good! The Joule-Thomson (aka Joule-Kelvin) effect is rather different from what we've been considering, the extreme form of which is expansion into a vacuum. The resultant cooling of a real gas is called the Joule effect. Anyway, I've really enjoyed this conversation, and wish you every success.

Comment: I would like to add that I wish discussions like these are provoked more at the high school and college level. Rather the teaching seems to be mechanical, just going over the Maxwell equations and writing equations on the board right away. Concepts like entropy, free energy, need more analogies and discussions like these. I believe you would make a good instructor based on how you explain away concepts. I'll bookmark this discussion.